# getting an ajax response into an array then checking if that array has a specific value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, response

I have a simple php script which queries a database to find a username and password match, if a match is found it echos 'success' else it echos 'fail|Those details are incorrect, please check and try again.'

I'm using ajax to trigger this function and perform an action based on the response data. The issue is that no matter what method i use, the if statement does nothing, though if i give a static value it works fine!! here are 3 of my 10,000 attempts:

method 1 - always returns -1

function userLogin(){
    $.post( sysFolder+'cmd.php?action=userLogin', $('#login').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            var arr = data.split('|');

```
        if($.inArray('fail',arr)){
            alert('no');
            //$('#login .msg').text(msg[1]).slideDown();
        }else if($.inArray('success',arr)){
            alert('yes');
            //window.location.href = homeFolder;
        }
    }
);
```

}

method 2 - arr[0] is recognised in an alert but if statements do not trigger

function userLogin(){
    $.post( sysFolder+'cmd.php?action=userLogin', $('#login').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            var arr = data.split('|');

```
        if(arr[0] == 'fail'){
            alert('no');
            //$('#login .msg').text(msg[1]).slideDown();
        }else if(arr[0] == 'success'){
            alert('yes');
            //window.location.href = homeFolder;
        }
    }
);
```

}

method 3 - triggers the fail action perfectly but is obviously not reading the php/ajax response

function userLogin(){
    $.post( sysFolder+'cmd.php?action=userLogin', $('#login').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            var arr = 'fail';

```
        if(arr[0] == 'fail'){
            alert('no');
            //$('#login .msg').text(msg[1]).slideDown();
        }else if(arr[0] == 'success'){
            alert('yes');
            //window.location.href = homeFolder;
        }
    }
);
```

}

here is a link to the current site which is currently trying to use method 2 as above http://57bit.com/admin/
PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Sintax for jQuery post functon is:

`jQuery.post( url, [data,] [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),] [dataType] )`

So you should define de success function as:

```
function(data,status,jqXHR) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response francadaval. However i may not have been clear enough. It's the if statement that doesn't appear to be reading the arr[0].

if i alert arr[0] i get 'fail' or 'success' as expected, but the if statement doesn't see this

Comment: my success / fail comes from a php echo in cmd.php where the database is queried

Comment: from jQuery page: _The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match._ **If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.**

Answer (score 0):

The same values were being read differently in the if statements! So I added the `$.trim()` function to the queried values to clear any other unwanted spaces etc. My code now looks like this:

```
$.post( sysFolder+'cmd.php?action=userLogin', $('#login').serialize(),
    function(data) {
        var arr = data.split('|');
        if($.trim(arr[0]) == 'no'){
            $('#login .msg').text(arr[1]).slideDown();
        }else if($.trim(arr[0]) == 'yes'){
            window.location.href = homeFolder;
        }
    }
);
```